# How can i query the last data from 3 tables

Tags: postgresql

now i have 3 tables, for example A,B,C
the relation between them is A onetomany B, B onetomany C.
C is a table saved photos
now i want get data from A, but only the last photo each A.

the colomns maybe like this:

```
table a:
id     a_msg
a1     msg in a
a2     msg in a
a3     msg in a

table b:
id     b_msg             a_id
b1     some data in b    a1
b2     some data in b    a1   
b3     some data in b    a2
b4     some data in b    a3


table c:
id    url           createdate                   c_msg              b_id
c1    /file/1.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.600      some data in c     b1
c2    /file/2.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.601      some data in c     b1
c3    /file/3.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.602      some data in c     b1
c4    /file/4.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.603      some data in c     b2
c5    /file/5.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.604      some data in c     b2
c6    /file/6.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.605      some data in c     b3
```

the result i want get

```
c_id url           createdate                c_msg            b_msg            b_id  a_msg    a_id

c6   /file/6.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.605   some data in c   some data in b   b3    msg in a  a1
c5   /file/5.jpg   2014-12-01 06:55:54.604   some data in c   some data in b   b2    msg in a  a1
```

---

Sorry ,i don't know how to use tool to describle the table,hope you can easily understand what i mean.

if my description is not clear enough,i will edit the question,thank you if anyone can help me

Comment: Can you please post complete "create table" etc. to better understand your structure. Is e.g. "id" auto_increment or how do you ever know whats "last" ? (select * from A order by id desc;)

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output (*formatted* text please). Ideally as SQL statements or even better as a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Now I add a colomn named createdate.Sorry but i just examined my question,now i think it's better now.

Comment: @user2545386 last data means the highest _date_ in _table c_'s column  `createdate ` ?

Comment: select * from a where id in ( select id from b where id in ( select id from c )) order by id desc limit 1; -- or rather use join

Comment: @user2545386 tell what exactly is your search criteria ?? I think the last data should be from rows in `table_c`'s `createdate` `2014-12-01 06:55:54.605` and `2014-12-01 06:55:54.604`

Comment: @WingedPanther Yes,what you said is right.I have examined and edited the question one time again.And i am testing the answer from Andy Thompson.Even though some more ideasis better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following as an example :

```
create table table_a (id int,a_msg text);

create table table_b (id int,b_msg text,a_id int);

create table table_c (id int,url text,createdate timestamp with time zone,c_msg text ,b_id int);
```

and the data

```
insert into table_a values (1,'msg in table_a')
                          ,(2,'2nd msg in table_a')
                          ,(3,'3rd msg in table_a');

insert into table_b values (20,'msg in table_b',1)
                          ,(21,'2nd msg in table_b',2)
                          ,(22,'3rd msg in table_b',3);

insert into table_c values (30,'url','2014-12-01 06:55:54.600','msg in table_c',20)
                           ,(31,'url 1','2014-12-01 06:55:54.604','2nd msg in            table_c',21)
                           ,(32,'url 2','2014-12-01 06:55:54.605','3rd msg in table_c',22);
```

to get the result you need to use `INNER JOIN` and to get the *last two data* use  `order by   createdate desc limit 2`

```
 select c.id,c.url
       ,c.createdate
       ,c.c_msg,b.b_msg
       ,b.id bi_id,a.a_msg
       ,a.id a_id 
 from 
       table_c c inner join table_b b on c.b_id=b.id /* to get data from table_b */
                 inner join table_a a  on b.a_id=a.id /*  to get data from table_a */
 order by createdate desc limit 2 /*  DESC will sort from the highest date time values and LIMIT 2 will return two rows */
```

---

[>**SQLFIDDLE DEMO WITH OP'S DATA**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4f566/5/0)

Comment: **c6->b3->a2**
**c5->b2->a1**
They are from different a,so c6 and c5 is the last result.
**c4->b2->a1**
c5 and c4 are both a1,and c5 created later than c4,so c4 is not the result i want.I think the answer isn't what I want.

Comment: @user2545386 Sorry, I didn't get you !!

Comment: @user2545386 my answer is just a an example to make you understand how to achieve your need. you carefully check the Inner join and order by clause with my example to get the idea

Comment: @user2545386 or just wait let me try with example data that you've given

Comment: @user2545386 I recommend you to change `id` field type to _INTEGER_

Comment: @user2545386 since your id field is varchar try like this `select c.id,c.url
       ,c.createdate
       ,c.c_msg,b.b_msg
       ,b.id bi_id,a.a_msg
       ,a.id a_id 
 from 
       table_c c inner join table_b b on trim(c.b_id)=trim(b.id)
                 inner join table_a a  on trim(b.a_id)=trim(a.id) 
where trim(c.id) in (select  trim(id)  from table_c  order by createdate desc limit 2)`

Comment: I have solved my problem.The sql is like this `select * from 
(SELECT b.a_id, b.id from b where createdate in (select min(createdate) from b group by a_id)) as se
inner join 
(SELECT c.b_id, c.id,c.url from c as c where createdate in (select min(createdate) from c GROUP BY b_id)) as ei
on se.id = ei.b_id;
`  , unfortunately there is no data of a in it,but I think one more inner join can solve this problem.Id in my table is uuid,so they are not integer.I haven't test your answer,I will review this question someday but not now because of time limit.Sorry and thanks.